# MySQL showprocess showing "System lock" taking a long time

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I am trying to troubleshoot some MySQL performance issue.
Performance degradation happened on Dec 17.
When I examined `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, I see

```
Time | State
```

Having a spike in time for `State = "System lock"`.
Before Dec 17, `System lock` would consume more than 5 seconds.
On Dec 17, it started to take up to 500+ seconds on a good number of queries everyday.  Some spiked to 50 seconds, some are 100+ range, worse case to peak out at 500 seconds. I have scanned the inno logs but nothing stands out.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Were you running `PROCESSLIST` as "root"?  Else you won't see other connections.  What version are you running?

Comment: I am not allowed to run as "root".   Version is 14.14

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose if you don't have permissions.

Comment: I found out more.  The MySQL instance is running on top of an NFS mount disk drive.   I suspect I/O problem but not sure how to read nfsiotstat output.    So I am asking that in a separate thread.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894985/how-should-i-read-nfsiostat-output